# Hash Map is updating values of other Objects in while updating the intended values

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a list like below which I want to order by client number in a hashMap. The list have two client's information.

list [BookRecord [clientNumber=1, columnNames=[name], data=[abc def]], BookRecord [clientNumber=2, columnNames=[name], data=[ghi gkl]], BookRecord [clientNumber=1, columnNames=[address], data=[1213]], BookRecord [clientNumber=2, columnNames=[address], data=[456]]]

I'm trying this with the following code.

```
public static Map<String, BookRecord> process(List<BookRecord> bookRecords) {
        Map<String, BookRecord> processedMap = new HashMap<String, BookRecord>();
        for (BookRecord bookRecord : bookRecords) {
            BookRecord existingBook = processedMap.get(bookRecord.getClientNumber());
            
            if(existingBook != null) {
                existingBook.addRecords(bookRecord);
            } else {
                processedMap.put(bookRecord.getClientNumber(), bookRecord);
            }
        }
        
        return processedMap;
    }
```

As soon as existing book is not empty and I add values to the existing one I can see column names getting added to the other record(client 2) too. The column names and data are created in the same way. below is the code that I'm adding the records

```
public void addRecords(BookRecord bookRecord) {
        if ( this.columnNames.isEmpty()) {
            this.columnNames = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        this.columnNames.addAll(bookRecord.getColumnNames());
        if ( this.data.isEmpty()) {
            this.data = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        this.data.addAll(bookRecord.getData());
        
    }
```

I can't ignore duplicates as there can be duplicated values with I shouldn't ignore.

Because of column names being added twice the final answer look like this
{1=BookRecord [clientNumber=1, columnNames=[name, address, address], data=[abc def, 1213]], 2=BookRecord [clientNumber=2, columnNames=[name, address, address], data=[ghi gkl, 456]]}

When I tried on another computer address was read first hence name was duplicated. I tried coping the value and deleting it but as soon as I update the second record gets updated.
Expected -->  {1=BookRecord [clientNumber=1, columnNames=[name, address], data=[abc def, 1213]], 2=BookRecord [clientNumber=2, columnNames=[name, address], data=[ghi gkl, 456]]}
Please help me

Comment: Please add an [mre].

Comment: can you post how the expected output should look like (according to the given input above) ?

Comment: expected output should be  {1=BookRecord [clientNumber=1, columnNames=[name, address], data=[abc def, 1213]], 2=BookRecord [clientNumber=2, columnNames=[name, address], data=[ghi gkl, 456]]}

Comment: It seems that your `BookRecord`s share the list of columnnames. Can you show how you construct the `BookRecord` objects for the initial list?

Answer (score 0):

My answer requires Java 8 or higher.
Your `BookRecord` class:

```
public class BookRecord {

    private String clientNumber;
    private List<String> columnNames;
    private List<String> data;

    // getters, setters and all that stuff

    public static BookRecord mergeBookRecordData(List<BookRecord> bookRecords) {
        return bookRecords.stream()
                .reduce((r1, r2) -> {
                    r1.getColumnNames().addAll(r2.getColumnNames());
                    r1.getData().addAll(r2.getData());
                    return r1;
                }).get();
    }
}
```

This method should do the trick:

```
public List<BookRecord> orderByClientNumber(List<BookRecord> unordered) {

        // first group by client number
        Map<String, List<BookRecord>> groupedByClientNumber = unordered
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(BookRecord::getClientNumber));

        // merge data
        List<BookRecord> orderedRecords = groupedByClientNumber
                .values()
                .stream()
                .map(BookRecord::mergeBookRecordData)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return orderedRecords;
    }
```

Comment: Hi IKO, Thank you. I tried this. It's still the same having address twice in both objects.

Comment: @Samydilini I tested the solution and it gives the exact same output that you posted as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Issue was not with this code it was where I was generating the initial list. I was reading columns of one and adding them to the rest of the records from one file. Hence both the columnName objects shared the same ID. All I had to do was to wrap the newly created column names inside a new Arraylist  as in -> new ArrayList<>(columnNames)